# Push ViewController from UITextfield text

Tags: swift, uitextfield, pushviewcontroller

I want to create a very simple view controller where the user enters a phrase into the UItextfield, which if corrects takes them to another viewcontroller. Exactly like a username/password screen. However, all the videos and examples i've looked up are outdated and do not work for me. Does anyone have any basic lines of code I may use as an example?

Comment: A simple search on this site will give you each unit you're looking for , textfield validation and push viewController

Comment: Thanks, I guess I wasn't using the correct terms.

Comment: I already prepared an answer, and couldn't post it because meanwhile it was marked as a duplicate... Sad

Comment: can you comment it here? or paste it? I'm still looking =\

Comment: I figured out the push code, but can't seem to figure out the "if password = this" then "push code"